# Factorial con for en javascript

Tags: javascript, factorial

Tengo una duda... en este ciclo `for` estoy tratando de imprimir el calculo de un factorial de forma que el numero se imprima seguido de una **x** y el ultimo numero arroje un **=** junto con el resultado. Mi duda es como elimino la ultima **x**.

```javascript
for (i=5; i>0;i--){
  
document.write(i)
  
 for (var j= 2; j>1 ; j--){document.write(" x ");}
            
};
```

Comment: Tenes un buen editor en la pagina como para mostrar tu codigo completo y en un formato adecuado

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te sirva, pero tengo esta opción donde se concatena el valor y se usa el *substring* para eliminar el último valor concatenado que, en este caso sería la **"x"**

```js
var num = 5,
a = 1,
qry = document.querySelector('.num');
var concat = '';
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    a = a * (num - i);
    concat += num-i+' x ';
}

var factorial = concat.substring(0, concat.length - 3);
qry.innerHTML = (num + '! = '+ factorial +' = ' + a);
```

```html
<span class="num"></span>
```